Best option for Belgrade to Sarajevo
I am planning an Eastern European and Balkans tour that departs from Budapest, then to Brasov and Bucharest (all by train) and from Bucharest to Belgrade with Air Serbia.
Now the plan is to go from Belgrade to Sarajevo, then Mostar and Split in Croatia.
I would love to get some suggestions on the best way to go from Belgrade to Sarajevo, unfortunately there is no direct train connection. I considered getting to the Serbian border by train (Zvornik), cross the border on foot and then take another train on the Bosnia and Herzegovina side, but apparently that route is used only by freight trains.
There is a bus but it's 8h30m at night and I know I won't sleep at all, so the next day will be wasted.
I contacted multiple transfer companies, all going in the range of 365 to 500 Euros one way, all in cash. By the way, is Serbia a cash economy or do these companies lovw cash? I am an Apple Pay guy and normally never use any cash in my home country.
I was wondering if it's possible to rent a car in Belgrade and drop it off in Mostar, but I doubt it's doable (I don't mind paying a hefty one-way fee).
The last option is taking Air Serbia again, but I wanted to avoid that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't have an answer for this particular route but in this part of Europe, busses or minibusses are usually the fastest and most comfortable option, trains not so much, driving yourself is also not that practical. Card payments are quite common in Serbia but I did need some cash as well (e.g. for the luggage fee on the bus).

Most of the few international train connections between the Ex-Yugoslavian countries were cancelled due to covid and have not resumed. Even domestic connections are in many countries, like B&H almost non-existent and in B&H limited to a few suburban lines around Sarajevo. If you want to minimise bus travel, your best bet going on land is probably to take the train from Belgrade to Zvornik and then a bus from Zvornik to Sarajevo.

The bus is the only reasonable option besides the plane. You'll find a list of bus services HERE - just change the date to when you wish to travel.
When buying the ticket at Belgrade bus station, either cash or card will do.
